# Is logic board from Macbook Air 11" A1465 2015 compatible with Macbook Air 11" A1465 2014?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, logicboard

I am thinking about buying [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MacBook-Air-A1465-MJVM2LL-MJVP2LL-2015-11-i7-2-2GHz-8GB-Logic-Board-661-02349/223842185708?hash=item341e08b1ec:g:UYMAAOSwaBJeFt6p) logic board and putting into into my Early 2014 11" Macbook Air, which has much lower specs.

Will it work?

Comment: I literally googled your question and found an thread about it, saying it works: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/453953/Does+MacBook+Air+11%22+2015+share+all+parts+with+2013-2014

Comment: Wow thank you! I searched a lot but found nothing, probably used wrong keywords... If you post this as an answer I’ll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these models the answer seems to be **yes**. 
According to an [iFixit thread](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/453953/Does+MacBook+Air+11%22+2015+share+all+parts+with+2013-2014) you can even exchange it with the 2013 model.

In general though, you have to be careful since Apple tends to make minor changes, making the models incompatible. 
For example: They changed the battery connector in the iPhone 6s from its predecessor, the battery itself was basically the same.